# Loop for continuous inflow information

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have 5 information coming at the same time like "long", "lat", "speed", "immat", and "date". At first, every 0.1 second new 5 of the info comes in for as long as info still available, then each time another set of the new 5 info available, another round of the same thing happen. I would like to know how to temporary keep all this values and display it.

```
var myPin = Table_Pins[immat];
myPin.Lat[i] = document.getElementById("Lat");
myPin.Long[i] = document.getElementById("Long");
myPin.immat[i] = document.getElementById("immat");
myPin.date[i] = document.getElementById("date");
myPin.speed[i] = document.getElementById("vitesse");

for (i=0; i<myPin.length; i++){
document.write("lat=" +myPin.Lat[i]);
document.write("long=" +myPin.Long[i]);
document.write("immat=" +myPin.immat[i]);
document.write("date=" +myPin.date[i]);
document.write("speed=" +myPin.speed[i]);

}
```

Comment: is your page getting refresh for every 0.1sec? what is Table_Pins[immat] for?

Comment: what i posted is an extrat of the code that i'm working on for google maps api v3. I said 0.1 second is just an example. It's not the refresh time of webpage, but time for info from db to be retrieve. In reality alot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object` to store data inside an `Array`:

```
var pins = []; //this will contain a list of your objects, it's better than keeping an object containing arrays

//inside your function that stores data you will have this
var pin = {
        lat: document.getElementById('Lat'),
        long: document.getElementById('Long'),
        immat: document.getElementById('immat'),
        date: document.getElementById('date'),
        speed: document.getElementById('vitesse')
    };
pins.push(pin);
//and after pushing it you could add to DOM dynamically without looping over al the pins
```

Assuming that you have a `<ul>` with `id="pins"` you can do something similar(just after the `pins.push(pin)`):

```
var pinUl = document.getElementById('pins'); //you can declare this after pins
//and now the code that adds an element to the HTML page
var pinLi = "<li>" + JSON.stringify(pin) + "</li>";
pinUl.innerHTML += pinLi; //append the pin at the end of the other
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/CqNuE/)

Remember to **avoid** `document.write`!

Comment: I added document.write because I wanted to see what will be shown for each set of information. Thanks for your answer, but what you written only store objects, i would like to know how to show it on the page?

Comment: Sorry but i'm very new to javascript and json. About the <ul>, i don't know what you mean ( i mean where to declare). From your answer, i didn't see any `code`for (i= 0; i> pins.length; i++) 
to display the all 5 info on page starting with 1st set and so on. How can we do that?

Comment: Thanks so much for your example, but that's not really what i'm looking for. I know that"pins.push(pin)" will save any information that it receive in "pins". But later i need to use it in another function for exammple : `var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long) ; `. I want to know is that for the "Lat" & "Long", should I replace with "pins.lat" & "pins.long" or "pin.lat" & "pin.long" ?

Comment: I understood what you're looking for. You have a stream of data continuously arriving from your server into your client and you want to store and display all the data incoming(supposingly without end) to the client. What I have provided you is an example of what will go on. Every time you call the funcion `addPin` it stores the new data **and** display it in the webpage. You have to change the code for what you need, the inputs are only an example of what is happening in your page. Is it clear now?

Comment: i added a new comment before your's regarding extra question.

Comment: If you do `pins.lat` or `pins.long` you will get undefined because Array don't have such properties. Instead you have to use `pin` as an object to retrieve its data in the form you told(which is right)

Comment: Ok, i tried with `pin.lat` & `pin.long` in following : `var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(pin.lat, pin.long) ;`. When i try to load the map in the program, it give alert " pin undefined" . What should i do?  Actually i'm working on google maps api v3, but my problem is the markers doesn't show up.

Comment: Where are you writing that code? Remember that `pin` is defined inside the function `addPin`, not out of that one!

Comment: As follows : 
`var pins = []; 
function AddPin()
{ 

      
    var pin = {
        lat: document.getElementById('Lat'),
        long: document.getElementById('Long'),
        immat: document.getElementById('immat'),
        date: document.getElementById('date'),
  type: document.getElementById('type'),
  site: document.getElementById('site'),
        vitesse: document.getElementById('vitesse')
    };
    pins.push(pin);
var vehlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pin.lat, pin.long) ;}` 
Please help solving the problem.Thanks

Comment: Post a fiddle with the HTML, if pin.lat and pin.long both alert undefined probably you're getting the wrong elements from the DOM

Comment: As I told you, there are no HTML elements matching that IDs, that's why you get `undefined`

Comment: no HTML element? how do I solve it? what should i add and where?

Comment: I don't know really... How do you get those information that you want to be stored and displayed?

Comment: because im working on google maps api v3 where i have a stream of data . I need to display the marker of each position and keep the info of each marker  inf infowindow and display them when user click on any marker.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a problem of global and local variance.Avoid defined var map in function when already defined `var map = null` in global. Only "map"is enough without "var" in a function.

Comment: Is there any chance you could post a little more context, outlining how you worked this out? The question as it stands doesn't lead to this answer.

Comment: sorry for the misleading. Actually this code is a part of my problem where i created to fix my initial problem, then i found out that the problem is about the variance as i explained , not about the code that i posted on this question to solve my problem.

Comment: ok. I believe that by 'variance' you mean 'variable' - am I correct? Also, you may wish to avoid global variables where possible, by using function closures.

Comment: yes, you are right, my problem to that post is solved but I have another problem if you don't mind helping out, here the post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021609/google-maps-v3-place-marker-and-polyline-with-interval
Thanks in advance