# Google Maps V3- Place marker and polyline with interval

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying for hours and also referred to a post in this forum but failed. I have a large number of markers, up to 1000 markers on the map. It slows down my map when I try to move the map's position. So I need to set an interval of markers to be shown on the map. Let's say with interval of 10 when there are more than 300 markers. How can I do that? Below is my code :

```
var trace_markers= [];
var pins = [];
var pin;
function Trace_Pin(Lat, Long, immat, type, site, vitesse, date){    
 pin = {
    latitude: document.getElementById('Lat'),
    longitude: document.getElementById('Long'),
    immat: document.getElementById('immat'),
    date: document.getElementById('date'),
    type: document.getElementById('type'),
    site: document.getElementById('site'),
    speed: document.getElementById('vitesse')
};
pins.push(pin);
ListPin();}

function ListPin()
{ 
var image_trace = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon61.png',
    new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(16, 16));


if (pins.length > 200){
for ( var i=0; i< pins.length ;i+10){   
  var vehlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pins[i].latitude, pins[i].longitude) ;
  var trace_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     position: vehlatlng,
     icon: image_trace  });
  trace_marker.tooltip_html = '<div class="tooltip">' + 'Date : ' + pins[i].date + '<br>' + 'Vitesse : ' + pins[i].vitesse + ' km/h' + '<br>' + '<\/div>';   
  trace_markers.push(trace_marker);
  trace_marker.setMap(map);
  Liste_Points.push(trace_marker.getPosition());
  TraceBounds.extend(trace_marker.position); }


   }
   if (pins.length < 200){
   for ( var i=0;i< pins.length ;i++){  
  var vehlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pins[i].latitude, pins[i].longitude) ;
  var trace_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     position: vehlatlng,
     icon: image_trace  });
  trace_marker.tooltip_html = '<div class="tooltip">' + 'Date : ' + pins[i].date + '<br>' + 'Vitesse : ' + pins[i].vitesse + ' km/h' + '<br>' + '<\/div>';   
  trace_markers.push(trace_marker);
  trace_marker.setMap(map);
  Liste_Points.push(trace_marker.getPosition());
  TraceBounds.extend(trace_marker.position); }
   }
  // Evenement MouseOver 
  //-----------------------------------------------------
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseover', function() {
        showTooltip(trace_marker);
        });
   }
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//**************************************************************************************
//                          On joint les points du parcours
//**************************************************************************************
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Trace_Route() {
   if (route) { route.setMap(null); }
   if (Liste_Points.length > 1) {
        route = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: Liste_Points,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2});
        route.setMap(map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array where you have all your markers (300 of them). 
Lets assume that is called

```
allMarkersArray[]
```

When you create a marker you do not set the map, but you leave it null so it won't be shown on the map. When you want to show the markers you do some math. Lets say that you want to show only the 1/30 (10 out of 300) of the markers. You create another array

```
shownMarketsArray[]
```

where you place the markers you want to show and when you put them there you set the map

```
marker.setMap(map)
```

Now the criteria of which markers will be shown, and which markers will remain hidden are up to you. If you want the 1/30 of the markers just have a for loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < allMarketsArray.length/30; i++)
```

You should take some precautions though (i.e. the array is too small and you want to show all of them).

**UPDATE**

```
if (pins.length > 200){
for ( var i=0; i< pins.length ;i+10){   
  var vehlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pins[i].lat, pins[i].long) ;
  var trace_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     position: vehlatlng,
     icon: image_trace  });
  trace_marker.tooltip_html = '<div class="tooltip">' + 'Date : ' + pins[i].date + '<br>' + 'Vitesse : ' + pins[i].vitesse + ' km/h' + '<br>' + '<\/div>';     
  trace_markers.push(trace_marker);
  trace_marker[i].setMap(map);
  Liste_Points.push(trace_marker.getPosition());
  TraceBounds.extend(trace_marker.position); }


   }
   if (pins.length < 200){
   for ( var i=0;i< pins.length ;i++){  
  var vehlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pins[i].lat, pins[i].long) ;
  var trace_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     position: vehlatlng,
     icon: image_trace  });
  trace_marker.tooltip_html = '<div class="tooltip">' + 'Date : ' + pins[i].date + '<br>' + 'Vitesse : ' + pins[i].vitesse + ' km/h' + '<br>' + '<\/div>';     
  trace_markers.push(trace_marker);
  trace_marker[i].setMap(map);
  Liste_Points.push(trace_marker.getPosition());
  TraceBounds.extend(trace_marker.position); }
   }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i thought of trying that but from
`for(var i = 0; i < allMarketsArray.length/30; i++)`
it will only  show the first 10 marker, while the next 290 is ignore,isn't? 
I wanted it to show markers with interval of 10, means I show the 1st; 10th, 20th and so on. I don't know if there exist a simple code for the interval?

Comment: just increase the step. for(var i = 0; i < allMarketsArray.length/30; i = i + step). Where step is whatever you want. The problem is not how to take the subset, but the criteria.

Comment: ok, i got what you mean, here is my code `if (trace_markers.length > 200){
    for(var i = 0; i < trace_markers.length; i+10)
   trace_marker[i].setMap(map);
    }
    if (trace_markers.length < 200){
    trace_marker.setMap(map);}`
I insert before the end of the function and remove the `trace_marker.setMap(map);` that i put in the first place, but it did not work, what did i miss?

Comment: Update your question and your code and be specific about the problem. What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: ok, i updated the code again as shown above, the problem is "1" is null or undefined. how can it be like that?

Comment: You have to start from zero. Your array's first element is in [0]. Try changing that, and print the length of your array before the loop.

Comment: ok,i tried, same error with "0" is null or undefined. By the way, what do you mean by `print the length of your array before the loop` ?how do i do it?

Comment: for ( var i=1; i< pins.length ;i = i+10){
check the third section.
As for the print alert(pins.length) or console.log(pins.length) 
The second one will print it in your console (press F12 in chrome and console)

Comment: from the print, it start with "1" for alert(pins.length) since i'm using js.

Comment: i updated my code. I try alert(pins.length) and it show number "1", then "2" and it continues. In between the print value, it show "0" is null or undefined and continues each time print window appear. I don't know where i did wrong.

Comment: Check my update. You had inside the loop pin.lat[i] etc. pin is an object that has attribute lat which you access like this pin.lat . Inside the loop you have an array of pin, pins[] and when you want to access lat of a pin, pins[i].lat . The same applies to all attributes

Comment: And maybe you should change long attribute. I think it holds special meaning to javascript

Comment: I tried,and also change the long to longitude, but still doesn't work. The reason i'm doing this is because when i have more than 300 markers and polyline, the map become very slow. and when more than 600 markers, it takes up to 2 seconds to load the map when i zoom ou drag to another position. By the way, i updated the code above.